# angular 1.5 passes undefined value to a controler after state.Provider "resolve"

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, state

I have this code:

app.js

```
var promptoWeb = angular.module('promptoWeb', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMessages',
    'ngAria', 'ui.router', 'ui.sortable', 'ngFileUpload']);
(function (app) {

    app.factory('env', function () {
        var domain = {domain: "http://localhost:8860/Elton"};

        return domain;
    });


    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$compileProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {

            self = this;
            $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $stateProvider.state('home', {
                url: '/',
                template: '<home-component></home-component>',
                component: 'homeComponent',
                params: {
                    selectedFilter: undefined
                },
                resolve: {
                    ldapGroup: function (authorizationService) {
                        return authorizationService.getLdapGroup() === 'WazeAdOps';
                    }
                }
            })
        }]);

})(promptoWeb);
```

and home-component.js

```
(function (app) {
    app.component('homeComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home-partial.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state, ldapGroup) {

            var self = this;

            self.isFullList = false;
            self.ldapGroup = ldapGroup;


            self.addVoice = function () {
                $state.go("add");
            };

            $scope.$broadcast('searchNoFilter');
        }]
    });

})
(promptoWeb);
```

why do i get an error in home-component that `ldapGroup is undefined?

and if I change to:

```
(function (app) {
    app.component('homeComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home-partial.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'ldapGroup',function ($scope, $state, ldapGroup) {
```

I get an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ldapGroupProvider <- ldapGroup
```

I have also tried:

```
(function (app) {
    app.component('homeComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home-partial.html',
        bindings: {
            ldapGroup: '<'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {

            var self = this;

            self.isFullList = false;
            $scope.isAdOps = !self.ldapGroup? true : self.ldapGroup;
```

I get `self.ldapGroup === undefined`

Answer (score 0):

> why do i get an error in home-component that ldapGroup is undefined?

Because you've told Angular to inject $scope and $state, so the third argument of the function is undefined.

```
controller: ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state, ldapGroup)
```

> I get an error:
>
> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ldapGroupProvider <- ldapGroup

Because there is no service named `ldapGroup`. `ldapGroup` is a resolve of your state, which can be injected into the controller of that state. But your state has no controller. It has a component.

How to use components, and how resolves are bound to inputs of the component, is described in [the documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component)

Comment: I have tried the input binding as well and i get `self.ldapGroup` has value `undefined`

Comment: You have template and component defined on your state. A component already has a template. This is wrong (as the documentation also shows). Also, the binding will be set in $onInit. You shouldn't try to access it before that.

Comment: This part is working for me. the template is the html tags to replace (like a place holder) with the component's defined template. no?

Comment: No. Why do you think the official documentation would be wrong? You tell the state that it must use the component homeComponent. Why would the state need any template? The component homeComponent **already** has a template defined. All the router must do is use the template of the component and put it inside the ui-view.

Comment: still, i didn't help with the binding. stays undefined