# resolving form angular router set the input param to `undefined`

Tags: angularjs, binding, routes, angular-ui-router

I tired to follow this [tutorial](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#example-plunker-1)

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$compileProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {

        self = this;
        $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/',
            //template: '<home-component></home-component>',
            component: 'homeComponent',
            params: {
                selectedFilter: undefined
            },
            resolve: {
                isAdOps: function () {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        })
```

and

```
(function (app) {
    app.component('homeComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home-partial.html',
        bindings: {
            isAdOps: '<'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {

            var self = this;

            console.log("self.isAdOps = " + self.isAdOps);
            self.isFullList = false;

            // this.$onChanges = function (isAdOps) {
            //     if (angular.isDefined(isAdOps)) {
            //
            //         self.isAdOps = isAdOps;
            //         console.log("self.isAdOps = " + self.isAdOps);
            //         $scope.isAdOps = !self.isAdOps ? true : self.isAdOps;
            //
            //     }
            // };

            self.addVoice = function () {
                $state.go("add");
            };

            $scope.$broadcast('searchNoFilter');
        }]
    });

})
(promptoWeb);
```

but still i get to the console: `self.isAdOps = undefined`

what is missing?

injection into the controller didn't work as well:

[angular 1.5 passes undefined value to a controler after state.Provider "resolve"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597133/angular-1-5-passes-undefined-value-to-a-controler-after-state-provider-resolve)

Answer (score -1):

When you resolve something, you can inject it. It is not added to controller as property automatically:

```
 controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'isAdOps', function ($scope, $state, isAdOps) {

            var self = this;

            self.isAdOps = isAdOps;
            console.log("self.isAdOps = " + self.isAdOps);
```

Comment: didn't work as well: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597133/angular-1-5-passes-undefined-value-to-a-controler-after-state-provider-resolve